# Does an AWS auto scaling group shutdown the operating system of an EC2 before terminating it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

There is a lot of discussion at work about how our services will be shutdown when they are running in an auto scaling group. The main concern is allowing services to perform some tasks before the instance is terminated. For instance if I add a destroy method to a spring service in java is it reasonable to expect that method to be called before the instance terminates?

```
<bean class="com.github.moaxcp.service.Service" destroy-method="destroy">
```

In this case `Service` will stop accepting data and save current state to s3.

Or what if there is a systemd shutdown script that should run before an instance is terminated. In this case send any remaining logs to s3.

The [autoscaling guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html) mentions that when a scale-in policy is met an EC2 is picked and terminated. Does this mean the instance is not shutdown gracefully? Would our services be able to finish some tasks before the instance is shutdown?

The [EC2 Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html) gives some detail about what termination does. It first shutsdown the instance and then terminates. In this case the services may be able to finish some tasks before being stopped.

From the documentation it seems as if when the EC2 instance is terminated directly it will shutdown gracefully but when it is terminated by the ASG it will not. Is this true? Is there any documentation about this behavior?

Comment: Voted to close as this is off-topic for stackoverflow. Questions here should be related to programming. This is about server administration and is appropriately suited for serverfault.com.

Comment: The instance will go through normal termination, but if it takes too long to shutdown then it will be forcibly "turned off". You can get some quick shutdown activities to run, but don't do something that takes several minutes. The best way is to experiment to see what you can achieve.

Comment: @anothermh Maybe? I'm not sure since as a developer I want to know how my application is shutdown and as a system administrator I want to know how the operating system is shutdown. I'm also programming all of this in java and just need to know the behavior.

Comment: But you don’t have a programming question, you have an AWS question. Vote to close stands.

Answer (score 1):

You have got something called Lifecycle Hooks that lets you perform custom actions as an Autoscaling group launches or terminates. The hooks responds to scale-out events and scale-in events.

Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html for more information.